# Coverage report in Java 8

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, code-coverage

I have just started working with Java 8. I see a lot of streams and optionals. One question popped in my mind. Consider the following example taken from [this oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html):

```
String name = computer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
                          .flatMap(Soundcard::getUSB)
                          .map(USB::getVersion)
                          .orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

Or the next one taken from [here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList();

myList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is there any coverage solution, which can tell me if the `orElse` in the first snippet was used? Or some other, which tells me that the `filter` closure was not called at all, since the list was empty? Can any report, that the method reference in `forEach` was not used?

Comment: The data use for your test add un optional without any value and check that unknown appear.

Comment: The `orElse` invocation will always happen and it’s argument always evaluated before the invocation happens, so its coverage needs no evaluation. In case of lambda expressions, they are desugared into synthetic methods during compilation so every up-to-date code coverage too should be able to deal with them.

Comment: You are guaranteed that any operation in a "pipeline" will be hit when you use a "terminal" operation on your stream. So there is not really a need for coverage.

Comment: @fge: if the list is empty, I am pretty sure that String.startsWith will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

At least Clover seems to support coverage for closures. See [this](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/11/get-more-out-of-java-8-with-the-new-clover-3-2/) blog entry!

Example in Intellij:

[image]